# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0' after upgrading from vs2013 to vs2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

we recently upgraded from Visual Studio Community 2013 to Community 2017. My REST Service project started breaking after starting it (build passes). This is only happening on one out of 3 machines.
We are using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin for creating our REST endpoints.

The issue seems to be on loading System.Web.Http, the library is referenced to {solution_folder}/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.Http.dll.

The referenced dll is in referenced folder and also copies to bin folder when rebuilding. Interesting thing is that when I rebuild the project with VS2013 I can start the service manually, from vs2013 or vs2017, but when I rebuild the project with vs2017 and start it I get the following error:

> Inner Exception 1: FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Stacktrace:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred
>   HResult=0x80131604   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__b(IAppBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveApp(StartContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions
>   options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions
>   options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider
>   services, StartOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
>   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](String url)    at
>   PNX.REST.Service.ServiceAdapter.Initialize() in
>   C:\Projects\peaknx\PNX.OS\PNX.REST.Service\ServiceAdapter.cs:line 32
>   at PNX.REST.Service.PNXRESTService.StartAdapter(Object state) in
>   C:\Projects\peaknx\PNX.OS\PNX.REST.Service\PNXRESTService.cs:line 85
>   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>
> Inner Exception 1: FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Update:

It seems that only on my machine the build copies app.config file as ProjectName.Service.exe.config, where as on all others it uses Web.config.

Basically I never get my dependency redirection going and it always looks for System.Web.Http 4.0.0.0 instead of 5.2.3.0 since this part of configuration is not in ProjectName.Service.exe.config.

```
<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http"
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: That machine I would bet has an incorrect version of .Net or asp.net is not registered correctly. You are the only person who can practically solve this issue

Comment: i had a similar issue.  System.net.http has been moved to a nuget file.  Go into each of your projects in the solution. Go to nuget, search for the system.net.http nuget file. and upgrade all to use the latest version. see if that helps

Comment: Hey thanks for answers, small update: It seems that only on my machine the build copies app.config file as ProjectName.Service.exe.config, instead of web.config file, so basically I never get my dependency redirection going and it always looks for System.Web.Http 4.0.0.0 instead of 5.2.3.0
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was that when installing VS2017 you must check "ASP.NET and web development" in workloads in order for VS to recognize the project as Web project and use Web.config instead of app.config

Unfortunately if you miss this step there will be no useful error report, hope this helps someone thanks for the answers.